# Docusign Error: 'The envelope specified either does not exist or you have no rights to it

Tags: javascript, node.js, docusignapi

I'm new to docusign and while I was trying to implement it  and trying to access document list I got this error

```
API Call Result: 
 { errorCode: 'ENVELOPE_DOES_NOT_EXIST',
  message: 'The envelope specified either does not exist or you have no rights to it.' }
Error calling webservice, status is:  404
```

https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/{myaccountID}/envelopes/{envelopeID}/documents

accountID is correct and envelopeID I'm using is of a document with status `completed`(though, I've tried for both `in process` and `sent`) but same error.

https://eu1.docusign.net/MEMBER/ReportEnvelopeSummary.aspx

I've also added check tests in my program all the credentials and detail is perfect,I'm getting accountID,userId also. I've no clue why this error is occurring.

I'm using code given here (javascript)

ttp://iodocs.docusign.com/APIWalkthrough/getEnvelopeInformation

## DocuSignAPI

Answer (score 1):

If you're positive that the Account Id is correct and the Envelope Id is correct, then this error is likely due to lack of permissions.  i.e., the user credentials that you're specifying in the **X-DocuSign-Authentication** header of the request corresponds to a user account that was not the Sender of the specified Envelope, and does not have rights to access (via the API) Envelopes that were sent by other users.

The user credentials you're specifying in the **X-DocuSign-Authentication** header must be a member of the DocuSign account where the Envelope resides, and must have **Account-Wide Rights** (for API) enabled in its permission settings (enabling it to access Envelopes in the DocuSign account that it did not send).

You can check/enable this permission by logging into the DocuSign web console and navigating to **Preferences >> Users >> (Open user) >> select Permissions (button) >> enable the "Account-Wide Rights" setting >> Save (button)**.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue I believe.

The Docusign sandbox only supports envelopes made in the sandbox. More than likely you are trying to view envelopes you made using your personal account. If you create an envelope in the sandbox using your developer account, it will appear when you run the API.

Answer (score 0):

This Error can be caused due to retention period of envelopes, If envelopes retention period is exceed envelopes will be deleted from system

https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&rsc_301&bundleId=pik1583277475390&topicId=frq1583277404325.html&_LANG=enus